# Swagger not working with Spring REST API

Tags: java, spring, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

Hello i am trying to implement swagger with Spring REST, i am not using Spring Boot to create REST API's, i have used normal Spring REST API.

The problem when i run the application and if i navigate to this url

http://localhost:8080/spring-mvc-restfull-crud-example/swagger-ui.html

i am getting only the header of swagger-ui, there is nothing else. I am using Java config instead of XML config.

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.boraji.tutorial.spring</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-mvc-restfull-crud-example</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<properties>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring MVC Dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.10.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring ORM -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.10.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Hibernate ORM -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.11.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Hibernate-C3P0 Integration -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.11.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- c3p0 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Mysql Connector -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Jackson API for JSON -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Servlet Dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- this is for integrating swagger -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-data-rest</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Embedded Apache Tomcat required for testing web application -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <path>/</path>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

WebConfig.java

```
package com.boraji.tutorial.spring.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

import com.google.common.base.Predicates;

import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.boraji.tutorial.spring.controller" })
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**");
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");

        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }
}
```

BookController.java

```
    package com.boraji.tutorial.spring.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.boraji.tutorial.spring.model.Book;
import com.boraji.tutorial.spring.service.BookService;

import io.swagger.annotations.Api;

@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RestController
public class BookController {

    @Autowired
    private BookService bookService;

    /*---Add new book---*/
    @PostMapping("/book")
    public ResponseEntity<?> save(@RequestBody Book book) {
        long id = bookService.save(book);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body("New Book has been saved with ID:" + id);
    }

    /*---Get a book by id---*/
    @GetMapping("/book/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Book> get(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
        Book book = bookService.get(id);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(book);
    }

    /*---get all books---*/
    @GetMapping("/book")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Book>> list() {
        List<Book> books = bookService.list();
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(books);
    }

    /*---Update a book by id---*/
    @PutMapping("/book/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> update(@PathVariable("id") long id, @RequestBody Book book) {
        bookService.update(id, book);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body("Book has been updated successfully.");
    }

    /*---Delete a book by id---*/
    @DeleteMapping("/book/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> delete(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
        bookService.delete(id);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body("Book has been deleted successfully.");
    }
}
```

In the resources folder, i have db.properties file

```
    # MySQL properties
mysql.driver=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
mysql.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bookdb
mysql.user=root
mysql.password=root

# Hibernate properties
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update

#C3P0 properties
hibernate.c3p0.min_size=5
hibernate.c3p0.max_size=20
hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment=1
hibernate.c3p0.timeout=1800
hibernate.c3p0.max_statements=150
```

MyWebAppInitializer.java

```
    package com.boraji.tutorial.spring.config;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class MyWebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

   @Override
   protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
      return new Class[] { AppConfig.class };
   }

   @Override
   protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
      return new Class[] { WebConfig.class };
   }

   @Override
   protected String[] getServletMappings() {
      return new String[] { "/" };
   }
}
```

can you please anyone help me that what is wrong in this? is there anything that i need to add?

Comment: Where is your Swagger Configuration file?

Comment: What do you mean the header of swagger ui? Does the page loads, but you don't see your api, or nothing is loaded?

Comment: I referred this example, there is nothing swagger configuration in that https://www.callicoder.com/documenting-spring-rest-apis-using-swagger/ this is the example i referred

Comment: @wdc i mead the header part of the swagger ui, logo and search box that's it

Comment: @mallikarjun I referred this example, there is nothing swagger configuration in that callicoder.com/documenting-spring-rest-apis-using-swagger this is the example i referred

Comment: Then you only need to configure swagger correctly and annotate rest controller with `@Api`.

Comment: can you also post the `WebApplicationInitializer` class

Comment: @Nishanthd i added the WebApplicationInitializer please check it

Comment: Can you share the repository?

Comment: Could you provide your main class as well?

Comment: If you are using Spring Security, use the security configuration mentioned on **[Cannot open Swagger UI in tis Version 3 in my Spring Boot Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73073519/cannot-open-swagger-ui-in-tis-version-3-in-my-spring-boot-example)** page.

Answer (score 2):

You have not defined `Docket` bean and neither you have used the `@EnableSwagger2`

The configuration of Swagger mainly centers around the Docket bean. Swagger 2 is enabled through the @EnableSwagger2 annotation. Refer the below code.

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket customImplementation() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).pathMapping("/data").apiInfo(apiInfo());
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfo("ISW ADR Application",
                "ADR or  is another business line within the Issuer services business group."
                        + "The primary functionalities of ADR are maintained within the DR system (mainframe) "
                        + "Four main functionalities that are imported : "
                        +"  1)  Dividend Announcements"
                        + " 2)  Depositary Service fees" 
                        + " 3)  DR Fees" 
                        + " 4)  DR Gross revenue.",

                "ADR V2", "Terms of service", "xyz", "License of API", "API license URL");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not enabled swagger using `@EnableSwagger2` and also have not returned a Docket Bean. Refer [this](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-restful-api-documentation-with-swagger).

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket demoApi() {       
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.example.demo"))
                    .paths(PathSelectors.regex("/person.*")).build();
    }


}
```